# Blend tree not yielding smooth animation transitions

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create a character that can run in all directions, and stand in place. For this I created a blend tree as shown:[image: blend tree 1]

[image: blend tree 2]

and this is my code:

```
playerAnimator.SetFloat ("PosX", Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal"));
playerAnimator.SetFloat ("PosY", Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical"));
```

The result is in the following video. As you can see the result is very laggy and the transitions aren't good at all. Can you help with this?

[image]